# How can I send input tag value from HTML file to PHP file without form tag?

Tags: php, html

I have the following input and button tag in my HTML code:

```
<input id = "inputarea" type = "text" name = "inputarea" size = "40">
<button id = "sendMessage">Submit</button>
```

I want to take the value of the input tag and send it to a variable in my PHP file every time the user clicks on the button. I don't want to use a form tag because I don't want the HTML page to get redirected to the PHP file when the user clicks on the submit button. Instead, I simply want the input tag value to be sent to PHP where the value will be processed and then sent somewhere else. How can I do this?

Comment: This is what AJAX is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<textarea id = "displayChat" rows = "25" cols = "41" readonly></textarea>
<input id = "inputarea" type = "text" name = "inputarea" size = "40">
<button id = "sendMessage">Submit</button>
```

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sendMessage").click(function () {
        
        var message = $("#inputArea").val();
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "chatbox.php",
            data: {messageText: message},
            success: function(response) {
                $("#displayChat").append(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**chatbox.php**

```
$message = $_POST["messageText"];
echo "Message successfully retrieved by PHP";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are wanting to learn what AJAX is and how to use it.
It's not a matter of adding form tags. Its a matter on how you post the form data.

[jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)

You dont even need jquery. Is just the first example on a google search. You can use vanilla js to accomplish this.